# Изменение garage4 списка изменяет garage1, после garage4 = garage1 присваивания

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
val5 = 17
test2 = 20
i = 0

print garage1
>>>    [258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258, 258]

garage4 = garage1

for test2 in garage4:
  garage4[i] = int(test2) + val5
  i = i + 1



print garage1
>>>   [275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275, 275]
```

Почему в `for`цикле изменяется `garage1`?

Comment: Потому что обе переменные ссылаются на один и тот же массив

Comment: Посмотрите [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793872/variable-assignment-and-modification-in-python) с картинками. Заодно обратите внимание на оформление вопрса, берите с него пример для следующих вопросов.